# How to relate to 2 taxonomy with category

Tags: taxonomy

I really need your help my question is this, is it possible to relate to taxonomies? This is My Problem

sample:
My post type is "show"

taxonomies and the categories

location (Taxonomy)
Categories

- california
- alaska
- new york

genre (Taxonomy)
Categories

- comedy
- broadway
- romance

note: each location has 3 genres to choose
for example:

california (comedy, broadway, romance)

alaska (comedy, broadway, romance)

newyork (comedy, broadway, romance)

my question is how will make a query like:

displaying all "comedy" shows on "california" location

or something like

displaying all "romance" shows on "alaska" location

if u can send me codes for this ill be gladly appreciate it, i will try to analyze the stuff

again thanks alot

Comment: Sounds like you want to query by taxonomy.  Take a look at this: http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

I recently dealt with a similar, although much more complex problem where I had to guess taxonomy names that had no naming convention. I built a whole bunch of abstracted functionality to automatically build my queries for me - your need is simpler though, you might as well do these as the link above explains.

The thing to keep in mind is that there are many nested arrays in this situation. That can be the big gotcha in all this - the arrays can get confusing.

```
$query = array ( //array level  1
     'tax_query' = array( //array level 2
             'relation' => 'AND' // actually in array level 2!
              array( //array level 3
                  'taxonomy' => 'some_tax',
                  'field' => 'slug', // 'slug' or 'id'
                  'operator' => 'IN', // 'IN', 'NOT' 'IN', or 'AND'
                  'terms' => array ( 'some_terms', 'some_terms2' ) // array level 4
              ),//<--comma!

             array( //array level 3
                  'taxonomy' => 'some_other_tax',
                   'field' => 'slug', // 'slug' or 'id'
                  'operator' => 'IN', // 'IN', 'NOT' 'IN', or 'AND'
                  'terms' => 'single_term' // no need for array if only a single term.
              )
      )
);
```

Another important thing to look into is the distinction between 'relation' and 'operator'

EDIT: Modified to 'terms' values to show that it does  not need to be an array if you dont want to pass multiple terms. Also, when you do pass as an array, you can pass any number of terms you want.

Comment: Since when has `tax_query` taken 3 differing operator parameters at once?

Comment: Apologies that I was not clear, my intent was to show each possible option. I did the with field. I'll use one, and put the others in a comment

Comment: Thanks a lot , i really appreciate it a lot hope there will be more of you out there to help starting developers, more power ;)

Comment: <?php

$query = array(
 'tax_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'location',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => array( 'california', '' ),
  ),
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'genre',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => array( 'comedy', '' ),
  )
 )
);


$query = new WP_Query();


?> Doesnt Show Any Results

Comment: adolfozen: 'terms' does not *have* to be an array, but it can be an array if you want to pass more than one term - also if you do use an array, there is no specific number of items you need. I had 2 just as an example.

In your situation you should simply have:
`'terms' => 'comedy'`

and `'terms' => 'california'`